# For...In with custom object in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function doIt()
{
    var person={firstname:"John", lastname:"Smith", age:"25"};
    var x;
    var txt="";
    for (x in person)
    {
        txt=txt+person[x] +"<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("showtext").innerHTML=txt;
}
```

My question is: Why when I replace

```
txt=txt+person[x]+"<br>";
```

with:

```
txt=txt+person.x+"<br>";
```

the value of person.x is returned as undefined?
In the first iteration of the loop, x should be 'firstname'. So person.x should be equal to person.firstname, and thus return the value John. I would love to understand why it returns 'undefined' instead.

Comment: Because of javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `person[x]`, it means "look up the value of `x`, and then find that element in `person`". When you write `person.x` it means "look up the value of `x` inside of person".

`person` doesn't have an `x` element, so you're getting undefined. You really do just want `person[x]`.

Answer (score 3):

The Answer is:

Since **x** ist not the **property name** and the object doesnt have a property with the name/key **x**.

> person.x

is undefined.

This would be equivalent to

> person[**"x"**]   *(the subtle difference lies in the double quotes)*

what is also undefined.

For it to work with the dot-notation, you would have to write :

```
 eval("person." + x); // but this is evil 
 // Tested on win7 with chrome 45+
```

> so expression **eval("person." + x)** would expand in the first run to **eval("person.firstname" )** which returns **"John"**
>   ...

What I don't recommend, because **eval** can introduce may security issues.

**Update 1**

> **Disclaimer:**
>   With this answer i only answered the initial question, and tried to explain the problem. With *"// but this is evil "* i am suggesting not to use this approche.

Comment: Not only eval but also completely unnecessary.

Comment: It is just to make a point, that x is a String and not the name of the parameter, and mainly to answer the question to the full extend. :)

Comment: It is not unnecessary it was an answer to the question, an explanation why the things are how they are(what the initial question was). I was trying to teach fishing, not just hand over **a fish**.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case you're using 'bracket notation', where the value of the variable `x` is used to determine the property name.

In the second case you're using 'dot notation', where the property looked for is literally called `x`.

Answer (score 0):

x will be a string. eg "person" so you have to use [] brackets

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dot notation with a variable key. It will look up the property "x" which is undefined. person[x] is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will allow you to access an object's property using a variable if you use the square brackets syntax. Thus, person[x] will do what you are trying to do as long as x contains a string representing the property name. The syntax construction person.x is equivalent to person["x"].

Comment: Thank you all for your quick answers!